# Jetpack Compose How to download an image asynchronously and dispose resource when Composable is done?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I'm looking for native code and other libraries such as Coil, Glide and native code load image asynchronously.

```
/*
        Load the image in background thread.
        Until resource loading complete, this function returns deferred image resource
        with PendingResource. Once the loading finishes, recompose is scheduled and this
         function will return deferred image resource with LoadedResource or FailedResource.
     */
val deferredResource: DeferredResource<ImageBitmap> =
    loadImageResource(id = R.drawable.landscape2)

deferredResource.resource.resource?.let { imageBitmap ->

    // We need a MUTABLE Bitmap to draw on Canvas to not get IllegalArgumentException
    val bitmap = imageBitmap.asAndroidBitmap().copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true)

    val paint = Paint().apply {
        style = PaintingStyle.Stroke
        strokeWidth = 10f
        color = Color(0xff29B6F6)

    }

    // We need a ImageBitmap for Jetpack Compose Canvas
    val newImageBitmap = bitmap.asImageBitmap()

    val canvas = Canvas(newImageBitmap)

    canvas.drawRect(0f, 0f, 200f, 200f, paint = paint)
    canvas.drawCircle(
        Offset(
            newImageBitmap.width / 2 - 75f,
            newImageBitmap.height / 2 + 75f
        ), 150.0f, paint
    )

    Image(bitmap = newImageBitmap, contentDescription = null)
}
```

As of alpha-12 `DeferredResource` is deprecated

> @Deprecated("DeferredResource has been deprecated.  Use State
> instead")

How can i use `State` for loading and do i need to dispose bitmap when this Composable is done?

With `Glide` it can be as

```
@Composable
fun ImageDownloadWithGlideExample() {
    val url =
        "https://avatars3.githubusercontent.com/u/35650605?s=400&u=058086fd5c263f50f2fbe98ed24b5fbb7d437a4e&v=4"

    var imageBitmap by remember { mutableStateOf<ImageBitmap?>(null) }

    val sizeModifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth().width(150.dp)
    val context = LocalContext.current

    val glide = Glide.with(context)


    val target = object : CustomTarget<Bitmap>() {
        override fun onLoadCleared(placeholder: Drawable?) {
            imageBitmap = null
        }

        override fun onResourceReady(bitmap: Bitmap, transition: Transition<in Bitmap>?) {
            imageBitmap = bitmap.asImageBitmap()
        }
    }

    glide
        .asBitmap()
        .load(url)
        .into(target)

    Column(
        modifier = sizeModifier,
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
    ) {
        imageBitmap?.let { imgBitmap ->
            // Image is a pre-defined composable that lays out and draws a given [ImageBitmap].
            Image(bitmap = imgBitmap, contentDescription = null)
        }
    }
}
```

and i saw in some examples  `onCommit` and `onDispose` functions from `androidx.compose.runtime:runtime` which i cannot access even though it's implemented, is used. Is it necessary to use these functions or does Glide handle it?